# When will the IIS restart the website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I got some information form [restart website in IIS when changing values in the appSettings of the web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589684/restart-website-in-iis-when-changing-values-in-the-appsettings-of-the-web-config) so now I know IIS will restart the application poll not website.

As I know when I update the web.config the IIS would restart the application pool but sometimes I didn't update the web.config but after my deploy the website seems like be restarted. Why? because I update the website.dll or some other reason and how does IIS works to know the dll was updated and it should use the new dll to serve the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create/Update/Delete files under below folders will cause IIS recycle the app pool:

Bin

App_GlobalResources

Global.asax

App_Code

App_WebReferences

Web.config

Some resources:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tmarq/2007/11/01/asp-net-file-change-notifications-exactly-which-files-and-directories-are-monitored/

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77322/update-net-website-without-reloading

https://shazwazza.com/post/all-about-aspnet-file-change-notification-fcn/

[ASP.net C# requires IIS restart when new DLL copied to BIN directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196672/asp-net-c-sharp-requires-iis-restart-when-new-dll-copied-to-bin-directory)